# Get absolute path to a file create by openFileOutput method in Android

Tags: android

can you tell me what the full path of my xml file, which is created through the following method:

```
fileos = openFileOutput("new.xml", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Even better, Android will tell you that by itself. :-)
Use the following code:

```
getFileStreamPath("new.xml");
```

The SDK says:

> Returns the absolute path on the
>   filesystem where a file created with
>   openFileOutput(String, int) is stored.